# How Do I round XML data to 2 decimal places in Microsoft RMS?

Tags: xml, microsoft-dynamics

I need to round off the decimal value to 2 decimal places in xml.
For example, I need to display 23.4436 as 23.44.
Can you please suggest a solution for this?

I am using this in Microsoft RMS receipts to display the value on the receipt.

Comment: You should specify how do you output the XML, since the XML file itself is static making your question meaningless.

Comment: A little more information's necessary, I think. How are you forming the XML? Where are the original numbers coming from? XML's just a data format, it's the tool that's parsing/generating it that needs to A) Work out that 23.4436 is a number, and B) Work out you only want it to 2dp's precision.
Edit: CURSE YOU VIRUZZO!

Comment: @Geek On Demand - are you using xslt to display your results.

Comment: @GeekOnDemand I've offered up a potential edit to your question that might attract more useful answers. Basically just re-writing the title to include the tool you're using and adding some tags.

Comment: Actually i am allowed to use only a few functionality of xml in RMS Reciepts.
So, i derived a mathematical formula to get the result using xml functions.
    Floor(23.4436)+(floor(frac(23.4436)*100)/100)
Using this expression gave me the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as it stands, depending on the tool that's reading your XML data, there should be some way to identify particular tags as numbers and read them to decimal places.

In XSLT, for example, you'd use "format-number", as seen on the [W3 schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp) (also has the ability to try it out).

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(500100, "#.00")' />
```

Should do the job. (Thanks to Hatzi in the comments)

Comment: you probably want this one - <xsl:value-of select='format-number(500100, "#.00")' />

Comment: It's going to be the same approach though, and an example may help. :D

Comment: Actually i am allowed to use only a few functionality of xml in RMS Reciepts.
So, i derived a mathematical formula to get the result using xml functions.
    Floor(23.4436)+(floor(frac(23.4436)*100)/100)
Using this expression gave me the desired result.